# Android: how to use Espresso to test that a buttons bgcolor has changed when it's being held down?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to use Espresso to test that a button that has a color selector as it's background is really changing color properly when the user presses on it. However, when I try to do this with espresso the actual click is being registered so fast that the button performs it's behavior (starting a progressbar) and the test fails with "view not found". How can I test that the background color changed when the user presses on it without/before performing the button logic? Essentially what I'm looking for here is a way to simulate OnTouchListener's Action_Down.

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.somebutton)).perform(ViewActions.click());

Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText(R.string.somebuttonText)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(withTextColor(Color.BLACK)));


   public static Matcher<View> withTextColor(final int color) {
        Checks.checkNotNull(color);
        return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(TextView warning) {
                return color == warning.getCurrentTextColor();
            }
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with text color: ");
            }
        };
    }
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with string from resource id: <someid>
```

I also tried to do it this way and it fails with the same error:

```
    ViewInteraction somebuttoninteraction = Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText(R.string.somebuttontext));
    somebuttoninteraction.perform(ViewActions.click()).check(ViewAssertions.matches(withTextColor(Color.BLACK)));
```

I also tried like this (longclick instead of click) but still the same:

```
somebuttoninteraction.perform(ViewActions.longClick()).check(ViewAssertions.matches(withTextColor(Color.BLACK)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution (weirdly enough) was to do something long and convoluted like this:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText(R.string.somebuttontext)).inRoot(RootMatchers.withDecorView(CoreMatchers.is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))).perform(ViewActions.click()).check(ViewAssertions.matches(withTextColor(Color.BLACK)));
```

in order to search for the view not in the foreground of the window after the click.